# Square made of stars in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns, square

Does anybody of you know something like JetBrains Academy? Could You help me with this task? I know surely it is very simple but I really cannot do it. I have tried a lot of times.

https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/6715

Answer (score 2):

Only thing that changes in the square are the insides, so just check if you're at the first line or last line.

Not the most efficient but python makes it easy.

```
size = 4
for i in range(size):  # each loop prints a row
   print(*
      ['*'] +  # first star in the row
      ['*' if i in [0, size-1] else ' '] * (size-2) +  # inside stars of the row
      ['*']  # last star in the row
   )
```

```
* * * *
*     *
*     *
* * * *
```

Comment: The result gives a shape of 5 by 5 but OP asked for a shape of 4 by 4. Just to bring to notice.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I was playing around with the program just to test and I copied the output for `size = 4`. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The task creates a square of size `4 by 4`.

Try this :

```
size = 4

for i in range(size):
    if i == 0 or i == size-1:
        var = "* " * size
    else:
        var = "* " + "  " * (size-2) + "*"

    print(var)
```

**Output:**

```
* * * * 
*     *
*     *
* * * *
```

Now you can change the value of variable `size` and play around to make square shapes of any dimension.